# upcasting and downcasting in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, downcast, upcasting

I was trying the idea of casting in C++ using Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express and the use of dynamic_cast.
But somehow, when I run it, an cat object can actually perform dog behaviour.

Seem like **Dog *d = (Dog*)aa;** got the compiler confused. Any advice?

Below is my code.

```
`
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Animal {
public:
    string name ;
    Animal(string n) : name(n) {cout << "construct animal " << name << endl ;  }
    Animal() : name("none") { };
    virtual string getName() { return name ; }
    virtual ~Animal() { cout << "destruct animal " << name << endl ; }
};

class Dog: public Animal{

public:
    Dog() :Animal("") { }
    Dog(string n): Animal(n) {
        cout << "construct Dog" << endl ; 
    }
    void dogStuff() { cout << "hello woof...."; }
};

class Cat: public Animal{

public:
    Cat() :Animal("") { }
    Cat(string n): Animal(n) {
        cout << "construct Cat" << endl ; 
    }
    void catStuff() { cout << "hello meow...."; }
};

int main() { 

    Animal *aa = new Cat("Catty"); // cat upcasting to animal 
    Dog *d = (Dog*)aa; // animal downcasting to dog. ???
    cout << d->getName() << endl;
    d->dogStuff();
    Dog* dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(d) ;

    if(dog)  { 
        cout << "valid  cast" << endl ;
        dog->dogStuff();
        cout << dog->getName();
    }else
        cout << "invalid  cast" << endl ;

    int i ;
    cin >> i ;

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

construct animal Catty

construct Cat

Catty

hello woof....valid  cast

hello woof....Catty

`

Comment: 1. `using std;` is a bad idea. Google that. 2. Read up on `const` and references. . For example `Cat(string n)` -> `Cat(const string*&n)` saves on the copy

Comment: Downcasting to the wrong derived type is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
Animal *aa = new Cat("Catty"); // cat upcasting to animal 
Dog *d = (Dog*)aa; // animal downcasting to dog. ???
```

This is undefined behaviour, you will need some knowledge on the low level implementation with v-tables to understand why the call results in a woof. Until then, know that undefined behaviour should be avoided.

```
Dog* dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(d);
```

Since d is already a Dog*, the compiler is probably not generating code to do RTTI and simply assigning it, hence it succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dog *d = (Dog*)aa;
```

The parentheses style of type cast is called a [C-style cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), because it is designed to mimic the behavior of C.   In this case, the compiler performs a `static_cast`, which proceeds to downcast `Animal*` to `Dog*`, on the **assumption** that the underlying object is `Dog`.  Because the underlying object is actually `Cat`, the program is ill-formed, and anything can happen, including memory corruption.  C-style casts never do any run-time safety checks.

```
Dog* dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(d);
```

This cast doesn't actually have to do anything:  It's converting from `Dog*` to `Dog*`.  A run-time safety check does not have to be done, even though `dynamic_cast` is used, because `d` is assumed to be a well-formed `Dog*`.

### Advice

Avoid the C-style casts.  Make sure that any downcasts are valid.  I personally don't use `dynamic_cast` very much, but then the responsibility is on me to only downcast properly.

Comment: Note that there may not be a warning given for `static_cast<Dog *>(aa)`